# Problem uploading a file using the Evo File API

Tags: rest, seequent-evo

I've been trying to use the Seequent Evo File API to create an upload link and then upload a file, but I keep getting the error:
Bad Request

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you share the code that you're trying to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading via the File API you need to include the header and value:

```
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
```

This is a requirement when uploading to Azure blob storage.